# Правильно ли писать "закуп" вместо "закупка"?

Tags: лексика

Можно ли говорить и писать "закуп" вместо "закупка"?

Например: "Форвардные закупки сельхозпродукции - это широкая мировая практика. Многие государства проводят закуп не только продовольственного сырья в виде зерна и семян масличных, но и готовых к употреблению продуктов питания долгосрочного хранения".

На сайте https://www.ekburg.ru/news/2/51586-kak-pravilno-zakup-ili-zakup/:

В Древней Руси закупом называли человека, получившего ссуду (купу) и попавшего тем самым в зависимость от землевладельца (об этом узнаем из Большого толкового словаря русского языка под редакцией С.А.Кузнецова). Закупка же, согласно Словарю бизнес-терминов, - приобретение товаров и услуг за границей с целью ввоза в страну и продажи на ее внутреннем рынке. Но употребляется это слово и в значении оптовых покупок, говорит нам Толковый словарь Д.Н.Ушакова.

Поэтому неверно говорить: закуп товара. Правильный вариант произнесения: закупка товаров.

Из Национального корпуса русского языка:

А. И. Тургенев. Дневники (1825-1826)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1)
Бр[еннер] некогда предлагал выгодный закуп у него библий и новых заветов нашему библ[ейскому] общ[ест]ву ― но мы отклонили; ибо сами уже выписали стереотипного анг[лийского] мастера. [А. И. Тургенев. Дневники (1825-1826)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Н. М. Карамзин. История государства Российского: Том 2 (1806-1818)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1)
Законодатель говорит, что «холопом обельным, или полным, бывает 1) человек, купленный при свидетелях; 2) кто не может удовольствовать своих заимодавцев; 3) кто женится на рабе без всякого условия; 4) кто без условия же пойдет в слуги или в ключники, и 5) закуп, то есть наемник или на время закабаленный человек, который, не выслужив срока, уйдет и не докажет, что он ходил к князю или судьям искать управы на господина. [Н. М. Карамзин. История государства Российского: Том 2 (1806-1818)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Цитаты из русской классики со словом «закуп»

Следовательно, желающему чем-нибудь промышлять остается только современный закуп хлеба и чего-нибудь подобного.
Пущин И. И., Записки о Пушкине. Письма, 1856

Пробовали они и на комиссию закупы разного товара делать, и тут оказались провинности: купит негоциант щетины да для коммерческого оборота в нее песочку подсыплет, а не то хлебца такого поставит, чтоб хрусту побольше ощущалось — отказали и тут.

Салтыков-Щедрин М. Е., Губернские очерки, 1857

На сайте: http://adilet.zan.kz/rus/docs/P090001729_

Об утверждении Правил организации и проведения закупа лекарственных средств и медицинских изделий, фармацевтических услуг
Постановление Правительства Республики Казахстан от 30 октября 2009 года № 1729.

Из современных СМИ:

Египет увеличил закуп российского зерна, Турция и Иран — снизили

CША и Великобритания увеличили закуп нефти в России

Россия ограничит закуп импортных лекарств в пользу препаратов из ЕАЭС

Comment: https://www.ekburg.ru/news/2/51586-kak-pravilno-zakup-ili-zakup/   https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lower/14811

Answer (score 1):

Слово "закуп" есть в словаре Даля в толковании слова [**закупать**](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C):
ЗАКУПАТЬ, закупить, закупывать что, покупать про запас или в значительном количестве для продажи; запасать что покупкою; | покупать или скупать весь товар в одни руки... Закупанье ср. длит. закупленье окончат. **закуп** м. закупка ж. об. действ. по глаг. | **Закуп** и закупка также самый предмет, что закуплено, товар.

Нашлось также слово "скуп" в статье [ску́пывать](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C):
СКУПЫВАТЬ или скупать, скупить что, закупать все, что есть; покупать в разных местах, в одни руки. Скупывание ср. или скупание или скупление, скуп, скупка, действие по глаг.

И слово "окуп" ([обкупа́ться](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)):
Окупаться, окупиться, давать выкуп, окуп за себя, выкупаться, откупаться на волю, из плена, рабства и пр. Окупание длит. окупление окончат. окуп м. окупка ж. об. действие по глаг. || Окуп, выкуп, плата, цена, ценность вноса, либо самые деньги и имущество или послуга, окупающая что-либо. Крепостной внес окуп за себя и вышел на волю.

Думаю, сегодня грамотно говорить "закупка".
Возможно, слово "закуп" потихоньку начинает возвращаться в употребление?